# Java: Return an object that extends an abstract class which takes arguments

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

I've got an interface

```
public interface I
{
public AnAbstractClass k();  //Abstract Class constructor takes two arguments
}
```

For an implementation of this interface's method I want to return a generic object which extends that AbstractClass and also give it its  two argument constructor

To clarify what I want to achieve. In a class which implements I:

```
public AnAbstractClass k()
{
   //return a new implementing AbstractClass object AbstractClassObject(arg1,arg2)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "give its two argument constructor"?

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  Are you asking how to call a constructor?

Comment: Sorry for that. I mean the method which overrides the interface method will provide the returned AnAbstractClass object the arguments its constructor needs. (By definition AnAbstractClass has a constructor with two arguments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructors are not inherited, so subclasses of `AnAbstractClass` won't necessarily have a two-argument constructor. If a subclass *does* have a two-argument constructor, there is nothing stopping you from creating an instance of that subclass using the two-argument constructor and returning it:

```
public abstract class AnAbstractClass
{
    public AnAbstractClass(String foo, String bar) {
        System.out.format("created with (%s, %s)\n", foo, bar);
    }
}

public class BaseClass extends AnAbstractClass
{
    public BaseClass(String foo, String bar) {
        super(foo, bar);
    }
}

public interface I
{
    public AnAbstractClass k();
}

public class Implementation implements I
{
    @Override public AnAbstractClass k() {
        return new BaseClass("hello", "world");
    }
}

public class Demo
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        I i = new Implementation();
        AnAbstractClass a = i.k();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are sophisticated solutions for this problem (roughly: Everything that is related to dependency injection). However, in this case, there are not so many options: Someone HAS to provide these arguments, and they obviously can not be passed to the interface method. So you'll probably need something like

```
class Creator implements I
{
    private Object arg0;
    private Object arg1;
    void setArgs(Object arg0, Object arg1)
    {
        this.arg0 = arg0;
        this.arg1 = arg1;
    }

    @Override
    public AnAbstractClass k()
    {
        return new ConcreteClassExtendingAnAbstractClass(arg0, arg1);
    }

}
```

The drawback is that this interface might become more or less useless: If it was designed to be a factory, you can no longer use it in its abstract form...

```
I i = obtainFromSomewhere();
AnAbstractClass a = i.k();
```

but you always have to know the particular type

```
Creator i = obtainFromSomewhere();
i.setArgs(..., ...);
AnAbstractClass a = i.k();
```